# Ignite SQL thread pool queries example

Tags: ignite

Can any one please share a simple code to understand SQL thraed pool example in Apache Ignite,I try to execute a simple SQL query which insert records in table by using SQL thread pool.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand the question. Here is a list of Ignite SQL examples:

https://github.com/apache/ignite/tree/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/examples/sql

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But Ignite have thread pool concept and i am trying to execute SQL thread pool which can do some processing on my cache.

Comment: @romilkothawade Are you trying to issue an SQL query? If yes, then simply run it and Ignite will execute it in one of its internal thread pools.

Comment: Yes,i am trying to execute SQL query.Thanks for your answer.